# Difference between using (operator) and using (operator) ANY

Tags: sql, any

I cannot distinguish when to use operators like `=` only and when to use `= ANY`. They seem similar to me.
For Example, Here are two tables and the question is:
Write a query to display the salesmen which name are alphabetically lower than the name of the customers.
My answer is

```
SELECT * FROM salesman WHERE name < (SELECT cust_name FROM customer);
```

But the correct answer is

```
SELECT * FROM salesman WHERE name < ANY (SELECT cust_name FROM customer);
```

, meaning I missed a ANY. Can anyone tell me why I'm wrong and when to use ANY and when not to.
[image]

Comment: You pasted the same SQL twice, and please include the table definitions and data as text, not an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE name < (SELECT cust_name FROM customer)
```

This condition will return an error if there is more than one row in `customer`.  Why?  The `<` operator expects a *scalar* value.  A subquery can be used -- but only if it returns one column and at most one row.

SQL offers `ANY` and `ALL` to support such constructs (and `SOME` which is the same as `ANY`).  As the question is phrased you want `ALL`:

```
WHERE name < ALL (SELECT cust_name FROM customer)
```

If you wanted a name less than the *maximum* `cust_name`, you could use:

```
WHERE name < ANY (SELECT cust_name FROM customer)
```

In general, `ANY` and `ALL` are not commonly used.  Most people find aggregation simpler to follow:

```
WHERE name < (SELECT MIN(cust_name) FROM customer)
WHERE name < (SELECT MAX(cust_name) FROM customer)
```

There is a subtle difference when `customer` is empty, but that is rarely important (or the aggregation form does what is intended).

Comment: Isn't it ALL means to output the result only if all rows in the subquery returns true. If you use ALL, there will be no results as ```(SELECT cust_name FROM customer)``` must return some rows that are alphabetically smaller than ```name```. And btw thank you for your answer, I noticed the difference between < and <ANY now :)

Comment: @LightYagami . . . The question, as phrased, is not well-written.  I interpret it to mean "whose name is alphabetically lower than the name of ally customers".

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're not leveraging of the ANY / ALL usage, since you don't have a where clause in your sub query.

See example in w3school for better usage https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_any_all.asp

**< ANY** will be true if at least one of your sub query is true

```
WHERE name < ANY (SELECT cust_name FROM customer WHERE LEN(customer) > 0 )
```

**< ALL** will be true only if all your sub query is true

```
WHERE name < ALL (SELECT cust_name FROM customer WHERE LEN(customer) > 0 )
```